# Creating a histogram function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

Let's say I have an array of this form

```
[
   [val1,val2,val3],
   [val4,val2,val1]
   ....
]
```

UPDATE- sorry, I wasn't too clear on my requirement. I mean this

The output should be an array of objects like this

```
[ {[val1,val2,val3] : 1}, {[val4,val2,val1] : 1}],
```

I just realized, that this above json is phenomenally stupid, I think it makes more sense to create an object like this

```
{ selectedRowIndices: [rows that have the value], freq: the frequency}
```

I thought of underscore and using its groupBy function, and indeed, succeeded in doing this with simple arrays, using

```
groups = _(values)
  .chain()
  .groupBy(_.identity)
  .map((values, key) ->
    freq: values.length
    value: key
  ).sortBy((d) ->
    d.value
  ).value()
```

However, I'm not sure how to do it with the above array.

Comment: Flatten the array first? http://underscorejs.org/#flatten. Since you are working with the data in JavaScript, your problem has nothing to do with JSON btw.

Comment: then I don't know if I'm dealing with the stuff in the third column?

Comment: Are you asking for `.groupBy((d)->d[2])`?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Well, it it's simplest way, you iterate over the outer array and put the third element of each inner array in a new array.

Comment: What if you had two arrays with the same value in the third column, like `[ [val2,val3,val1], [val4,val5,val1] ]`? And notice that an array is no key (which must be a string)

Comment: then the frequency would be 2

Comment: But how would the result object look like? Maybe a more detailed example with a few edge cases would help.

Comment: so to answer your question , it would be [ {the arrays} : freq], but i realized that I could just have an array of row indexes, so 

{[0,1] : freq}

Comment: yeah Bergi - I've updated the question - I think that is an easier problem than what I was solving before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
groups = _.chain(values)
  .groupBy((a) ->
    a[2]
  ).map((values, key) ->
    value: key // the third column
    selectedRows: values // the rows that have this value
    freq: values.length // and their number
  ).sortBy((d) ->
    d.value
  ).value()
```

If you needed the indices, then replace the `groupBy` call with

```
  .reduce((m, a, i) ->
    k = a[2]
    (m[k] || m[k]=[]).push i // instead of pushing `a`
    m
   , {})
```

Comment: sweet, that looks like it works - is there a way to get the index of the row as opposed to the actual row in selectedRows?

Comment: You'd need to use a [group function](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-34) that pushes the `index` instead of the `value`.

Answer (score 5):

There's an even simpler function to create a histogram: [`countBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy). If you don't want to group by identity but by the third item of each array, you would write

```
_.countBy( (a) -> a[2] )
```

Comment: but I want to group by the number of occurrences of the third item of each array

Comment: You mean `_.groupBy(values, (a) -> _.reduce(a, (m, v)->m+(v==a[2]), 0) )`?

Comment: @praks5432: I see, needs a linebreak. http://coffeescript.org/#try:_.groupBy(values%2C%20(a)%20-%3E%0A%20_.reduce(a%2C%20(m%2C%20v)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20m%20%2B%20(v%3D%3Da%5B2%5D)%0A%20%2C%200)%0A)